# How to use Magento Controller/Template in ModX?

Tags: template, cms, external, extensions

I'm looking for a way to combine or to use a template from Magento in modx.
There is a template I had to use in several systems and I don't want to create it every time from the scratch. So I wonder if it is possible to call my Magento template in Modx.
But for now there are no helpful links in Google to get closer to this task.

So far I created a PHP file for Modx in which I require_once my Magento Controlle. But inside my Magento controller I use

```
extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

and Modx can't find this controller.